# SQL Math with Date/Time

Tags: sql, math

I have a table that constantly logs errors in a SQL db and logs it with a timestamp in the following format

2012-09-05 13:46:59.383

How can I pull only the last 48 hours from this error log?

Comment: What DBMS do you use and what data type is the column?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? Date and time functions differ quite a bit between systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for Sql Server, try

```
Select * from myLog where datediff(h, myTimestamp, getdate()) < 48
```

Comment: Don't do it like this. Applying a function on the column makes it impossible for the query to use an index.

Comment: `where mytimestamp >= dateadd(hour, -48, getdate())`

Comment: @mikaelEriksson - Thanks for the correction.  For reasons unclear to me I've always been leery of "where datetimeA > datetimeB" clauses.  Not sure why.  Time to change my my ways.